# Storing multiple form Data in local storage

Tags: html, local-storage

I have used HTML form to get vehicle details, and i want it to stored locally and need to use it in another HTML page, i want to store multiple numbers of vehicle details and want to retrieve it. My for consists of different properties like ID,capacity, engine number...etc.

Comment: can you please post your code? have you put some effort in solving this?

Comment: i am using HTML local storage , but there i do not know how to store multiple data in dictionary or array